# can i sign same app for multiple clients with same kaystore different package name?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

hello friends i created an app and i want to sell my app to multiple clients.

i know that i have to change package name for every client but i want to know that can i sing that same app with same key-store for multiple clients with different package name.

or should i sign app with different key-store for every client

if is there no issue with play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can.  There's nothing stopping that, and if you have a fleet of apps you generally do sign with a single key.

If you're releasing the same app to multiple clients as a whitelabel-  Google has changed their policies on that several times.  The last time I whitelabeled they used to say that the client should own the listing and have their own key and that you should just be an administrator on their account.  But that's a policy guideline and off topic here, you should look into the latest rules yourself.